# Load DATA INFILE Error when run from script on Infobright

Tags: mysql, shell

The query executes perfectly fine when run on infobright prompt:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.agg' IGNORE INTO TABLE tb_message_content FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\\'LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
Query OK, 2 rows affected
```

However, The same query gives an error when run from a shell script:This is how the script interprets the query

```
mysql -u amr_ts_scripts -pamr_ts_scripts MVR4_ETL_DB -S /tmp/mysql-ib.sock -N -e 
$'LOAD DATA INFILE \'/tmp/test.agg\'
 IGNORE INTO TABLE tb_message_content \n      
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' \n             
 OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'"\' \n             
 ESCAPED BY \'\\\'\n      
 LINES TERMINATED BY \'\\n\';'
```

The error cited is:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''\'
      LINES TERMINATED BY ''' at line 4
PAGER set to stdout
```

Can anyone point out the problem i am facing??

Comment: so is `$'LOAD_.... ` is meant to be a bash `$'str'`, and you're passing in the whole command, formatting and all, as a string arg via `-e`? Try switching to `$"LOAD ..."`, and leave out the escapes on the single-quote chars. Also, why complicate things having the `\n`s for formatting? leave those out until you get it working. Good luck.

Comment: to avoid escaping put your load statement into file for example load.sql and execute `#mysql {some_params} < load.sql`

Answer (score 0):

```
stmt="LOAD DATA INFILE '$1' IGNORE INTO TABLE $2 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\\\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

The above statement in scripts work because ESCAPED BY '\\' is required to escape each '\'.